# Antd word-wrap in Menu.Item

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

it is possible to apply word-wrap in a Menu.Item component ?

example not working: https://codepen.io/tiagowippel/pen/LYEKYbb?editable=true&editors=001

```
 <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1</Menu.Item>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you tried anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default CSS you're importing from Ant is set to truncate. You'll want to change the white-space property:

`white-space: normal;`

You may then notice that the wrapped text is overflowing in the y axis now. You can change your height to accommodate variable height content:

`height: auto;`

Answer (score 5):

You can set some style to your `Menu.Item` :

```js
<Menu.Item key="1" style={{whiteSpace: 'normal', height: 'auto'}}>Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1</Menu.Item>
```