# Subtitle or child element in Antd Menu.Item

Tags: antd

I see that you can [wrap words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987190/antd-word-wrap-in-menu-item) in an [Antd Menu.Item](https://ant.design/components/menu/) but I'm wondering if you can create a (styled) child element or subtitle for a menu item. something like:

```
------
**Item 1**
---
**Item 2**
This item is second
---
**Item 3**
------
```

I've tried adding a `<div>` or a `<p>` like the following but it just seems like it's hidden.

```
<Menu.Item key={eventKey} {...props}
    <span>{item.title}</span>
    <div>A styled subtitle here</div>
</Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use plain html elements and css inside the `Menu.Item`.

Maybe you need to play with the `height` or `lineHeight` settings and have a look at the `inspect` view.

This basic example worked for me:

```js
<Menu.Item key="1" style={{ lineHeight: '20px' }}>
   <span>
      Option 1
   </span>
   <br />
   <span>Test</span>
</Menu.Item>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lgysch) is a  working Stackblitz.

`<h1>` etc. elements worked as well.

Comment: Ah yep, I think the CSS was what I was missing because the height/lineHeight needs to be overridden. Thank you!